# How to make Items spawn when you combine two other items together

Tags: unity, c#

My Idea is to have Two Herbs from the Player's Inventory and give them particular Item IDs like:

- 2 Combined Herbs give you a Potion of Health.
- 2 different Herb combinations give you a Potion of Nature.

...and so on.

So far, I can randomly spawn potions, but I need it to be specific like each Herb Combination gives me a specific assigned Potion.

This is a picture from the scene of potion making:

[image: Picture from game am making]

Comment: If you want to allow user-generated potions *and* give proper names to a select subset designed by you, you should store such a list somewhere in your game and compare each user combination against it.

Comment: You may be interested in [How to implement combining 2 ingredients to create a product?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/141111/39518) Can you edit your question to show how your current random spawning code is set up?